# Server not receiving HTTP requests from Client

Tags: javascript, express, axios, request

First a quick preface I think may be helpful: I am new to splitting my client and server into separate web apps. My previous apps have all had my server.js at the root level in my directory and the client (typically a create-react-app) in a /client folder.

What I wanted to do: Host a single express.js server on the web which multiple other web applications could make requests to.

I did the first part using an express server and aws elastic beanstalk.

server.js

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

//ROUTES
const APIUser = require('./routes/api/mongo/api-user');
more routes...

//INITIATE DATA MAPPING CONNECTIONS START
Mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_URI,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    console.log("connected to MongoDB")
);

const Postgres = new Sequelize(process.env.PG_CONN_STRING);

try {
    Postgres.authenticate()
        .then(console.log("connected to Postgres"));
} catch {
    console.log("Postgres connection failed")
}
//INITIATE DATA MAPPING CONNECTIONS END

//middleware
app.use(cors())
more middleware...

//home route
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    console.log('RECEIVED REQ to [production]/api/')
    res.status(200).send('models api home').end();
})

//all other routes
app.use('/api/user', APIUser);
more route definitions...

//launch
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

The log file for successful boot up on aws: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k66WV.jpg

At first glance it seemed to work as my postman requests were working. Status 200 with appropriate response: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaZO4.jpg

Next I tested this from one of my actual clients **in localhost**. Here is one of my react client's api util files where axios calls are made to the backend:

```js
import { PROXY_URL } from '../../config';
import { axiosInstance } from '../util';

const axiosProxy = axios.create({baseURL: PROXY_URL}); //this was the most reliable way I found to proxy requests to the server

export const setAuthToken = () => {
    const route = "/api/authorization/new-token";
    console.log("SENDING REQ TO: " + PROXY_URL + route)

    return axiosProxy.post(route)
}

export const authorize = clientsecret => {
    const route = "/api/authorization/authorize-survey-analytics-client";
    console.log("SENDING REQ TO: " + PROXY_URL + route)
    
    return axiosProxy.post(route, { clientsecret })
}
```

Once again it worked... or rather I eventually got it to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCx0f.jpg

So I figured all was well now but when I tried using the live version of the client the request failed somewhere.

**in summary the live api works when requests are made from postman or localhost but doesn't respond when requests are made from a live client** https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBd7v.jpg

I have confirmed that the requests made from the live client do not make it to the live server (by making requests from a live client and then checking the aws live server logs).

I am not receiving any Cors or Cross-Origin-Access errors and the requests from the live client to the live server don't throw any loud errors, I just eventually get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Any ideas where I can look for issues or is there more code I could share?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `console.log(PROXY_URL)` in your client application and check your browser console if that's logged correctly.

If it works on your local client build, and through POSTMAN, then your backend api is probably good. I highly suspect that your env variables are not being set. If `PROXY_URL` is an emplty string, your `axios` requests will be routed back to the origin of your client. But I assume they have different origins since you mention that they're separate apps.

Remember environment variables need to prefixed with `REACT_APP_` and in a production build they have to be available at build time (wherever you perform `npm run build`)

Comment: Thanks for your input Ajay! The PROXY_URL is actually not an environment variable but rather a const exported from config.js so the client did in fact have access to it and this was clear to me because on client side I did have logging prior to every axios request and it was matching the proper proxy url.